# How to use @expo/vector-icons dynamically through props in typescript react native app?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

react native app with typescript and I'm trying to create icon button that uses @expo/vector-icons with Fontawesome or MaterialIcon dynamically by trying to pass a name as a string via props.

I think the issue is this, BUT don't know how to solve it. Any ideas? Suggestions? Also feel free to criticize other code.

Below is my IconButton component that receives the `name` prop

```
import { Ionicons, MaterialIcons, FontAwesome } from 
 "@expo/vector-icons";

const star = "star";

type Props = {
  name: keyof typeof MaterialIcons.glyphMap;
  color: string;
  onPress(): void;
};

export default function IconButton(props: Props) {
  return (
    <Ionicons.Button name={props.name} size={24} color={props.color} />
  );
}
```

[Fontawesome expo vector expected properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmIEV.png)

the 'name' property is the issue here.

This code is from a screen using `IconButton` where I pass the `name` as a string.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => {
        return (
          <IconButton
            onPress={headerButtonPressHandler}
            name="star"
            color="gray"
          />
        );
      },
    });
  }, [navigation, headerButtonPressHandler]);
```

[name property error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpRVN.png)

**edit**: updated code but still there is error on `name`

[updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhGq0.png)

[this is where I use `IconButton` and pass in `name`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLK8A.png)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your Props type, `name` should not be a string - it should only allow names that exist in your icon set.  If you look through the issues on Github for expo/vector-icons, you can see that others are also facing the same problem, and one has posted a solution:

```js
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

type Props = {
  materialIconName: keyof typeof MaterialIcons.glyphMap;
}
```

This solution and related discussion can be found here: https://github.com/expo/vector-icons/issues/153#issuecomment-752769305

One of the library authors also offers this solution:

```js
type MaterialIconName = React.ComponentProps<typeof MaterialIcons>['name'];
const iconName: MaterialIconName =  '3d-rotation'
```

https://github.com/expo/vector-icons/issues/153#issuecomment-787130328

Comment: Thanks thats helpful, but I still get an error in `name` saying: Type '"star" | "link" | "search" | "image" | "header" | "key" | "code" | "map" | "table" | "th" | "circle" | "filter" | "stop" | "forward" | "retweet" | "minus" | "plus" | "info" | "exclamation" | ... 766 more ... | "meetup"' is not assignable to type '"star" | "link" | "search" | "image" | "key" | "code" | "map" | "filter" | "stop" | "close" | "book" | "pause" | "home" | "laptop" | "save" | "cloud" | "eye" | "camera" | "heart" | ... 3661 more ... | "md-woman-sharp"'.
  Type '"header"' is not assignable to type '"star"

Comment: Can you show your solution?  This generally works, so there may be an issue with how it was implemented.

Comment: I just edited my post and you should be able to see it. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're using the type for FontAwesome, but the component from Ionicons.  They have different sets and names. Also, it would be helpful if you could paste your code in instead of using images, so your code is searchable.

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback! I'm new here so I appreciate it. I tried it with `MaterialIcons` just like your example and it gives the same error.

Comment: Hi, hopefully you have figured this out in the meantime, but you have to match the glyph map to the component you're actually using.  Your component uses Ionicons.  Therefore the type has to come from Ionicons.

Answer (score 0):

this helps

```
type Props{
iconName:   keyof typeof MaterialCommunityIcons.glyphMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but If you want to use multiple Expo vector icons as props in a custom component using Typescript. You can do the following

```
import { FontAwesome, MaterialIcons, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


export enum IconType {
  MaterialIcon,
  FontAwesomeIcon,
  Ionicons,
}


type CustomProps = {
   icon: {
     value: { type: IconType.MaterialIcon, name: keyof typeof MaterialIcons.glyphMap } |
            { type: IconType.FontAwesomeIcon, name: keyof typeof FontAwesome.glyphMap } |
            { type: IconType.Ionicons, name: keyof typeof Ionicons.glyphMap };
     size: number;
   }
   
}


const CustomComponent = (props: CustomProps) => {
const { icon, ...otherProps } = props;

return 
  (
    <View style={styles.customIconStyle}>
      {icon.value.type === IconType.FontAwesomeIcon && (
        <FontAwesome name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
      {icon.value.type === IconType.MaterialIcon && (
        <MaterialIcons name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
      {icon.value.type === IconType.Ionicons && (
        <Ionicons name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
    </View>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons, MaterialIcons, FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';

interface IconProps {
  iconName: string;
}

const DynamicIcon: React.FC<IconProps> = ({ iconName }) => {

  const IconComponent = Ionicons;

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Some other components or text here</Text>
      <IconComponent name={iconName} size={30} color="black" />
    </View>
  );
};
```