# React Native - expo/vector-icons typescript type definition for icon name

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to find out the type definitions for the icon name of ***expo/vector-icons***, since I am intending to use it for a component props.

I am import ***expo/vector-icons*** like and and defining interface props like this, I tried type icon name as string.

```
import Icon from "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome"

interface Props {
    icon: string
    value: string
    placeholder: string
    onChangeText: (text: string) => void
    secureTextEntry?: boolean
    style: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
}
```

This is how I am using the prop.

```
<Icon name={icon} size={20} style={styles.icon} />
```

But I get error from Typescript.
[image]

Comment: I think you might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72078720/how-to-use-expo-vector-icons-dynamically-through-props-in-typescript-react-nati) helpful. The name prop isn't a string but a glyphMap.

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you have to change the type of your icon Props,

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

and use glyphMap property from Ionicons, just like this

```
icon: keyof typeof Ionicons.glyphMap
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use multiple Expo vector icons as props in a custom component using Typescript. You can do the following

```
import { FontAwesome, MaterialIcons, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


export enum IconType {
  MatetrialIcon,
  FontAweomseIcon,
  Ionicon,
}


type CustomProps = {
   icon: {
     value: { type: IconType.MatetrialIcon, name: keyof typeof MaterialIcons.glyphMap } |
            { type: IconType.FontAweomseIcon, name: keyof typeof FontAwesome.glyphMap } |
            { type: IconType.Ionicon, name: keyof typeof Ionicons.glyphMap };
     size: number;
   }
   
}


const CustomComponent = (props: CustomProps) => {
const { icon, ...otherProps } = props;

return 
  (
    <View style={styles.customIconStyle}>
      {icon.value.type === IconType.FontAweomseIcon && (
        <FontAwesome name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
      {icon.value.type === IconType.MatetrialIcon && (
        <MaterialIcons name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
      {icon.value.type === IconType.Ionicon && (
        <Ionicons name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
    </View>
  );

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import Icon from "@expo/vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";
import { ComponentProps } from "react";

type Props = ComponentProps<typeof Icon>;
export type IconName = Props["name"];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP